# Send hotkeys own default behavior

Tags: autohotkey

How can I send a keys default (from hardware) behavior in its own key definition. I mean this code:

```
vcerc = 0

+c::
vcerc := !vcerc
Return

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

kkey = 0

$k::
if vcerc {
    kkey := !kkey
    if kkey
        SendInput {k down}
    else
        SendInput {k up}
}
else {
    Send, K
}
Return
```

In the end part `Send, K` It sends the word `K`. I am in a multi language environment which means if I switch to the other, This key still sends `K` rather than sending the one that is for the second language (assume `ن`).
How can I make this send the default? (From hardware with no matter what the language is)

Comment: What does the key show in Key History when you press it? (without the script running)

Comment: I'm a little confused on what you're looking for here. You want to toggle what the k key sends based on a bool?

Comment: @fischgeek yes, its a toggle for in game voice, but thats not the case. when I wanna type words and when I hit K it does not send the right character. (multi language platform as said)

Answer (score 0):

Two things that seem off to me: 1) Your initial kkey declaration will never get hit since it falls after a hotkey (and a return). Declare your variables at the top. 2) if kkey is true, your script has it holding down the k button indefinitely. Is this expected? 3) Your only looking for lowercase k's but sending uppercase k's. Is this expected?

At any rate, this example should point you in the right direction.

```
vcerc = 0
kkey = 0

+c::
vcerc := !vcerc
return

$k::
{
    if (vcerc) {
        kkey := !kkey
        if (kkey) {
            msgbox, k down ; SendInput {k down}
        } else {
            msgbox, k up ; SendInput {k up}
        }
    } else {
        Send, K
    }
}
```

Comment: Unlike what you said, It does not hold the K down indefinitely. (you can test it) but in game it shows that it is holding the K key. Anyway this is not an answer to my question. Does it send `ن` when I switch to second language using Alt+Shift ? It does not! It sends the char `K` again. which is not expected.